# Pythonic way to combine two lists with a semicolon between them

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']

list2 = ['4','5','6']
```

I have two lists and need to combine them but with a semicolon after end of each list.

```
list_join = ['1','2','3';'4','5','6']
```

I tried

```
s = ";".join()
```

but this gives me a semicolon after each element in the string, how to place a semicolon after appending one complete list.

Comment: So `list` (please do not use that name) is a `str`ing?

Comment: please clarify your question. `['1','2','3';'4','5','6']` is not even valid syntax. Do you mean you want it to look like this? `['1','2','3', ';', '4','5','6']` Or perhaps like this? `'123;456'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to format an appropriate string:

```
'{}; {}'.format(str(list1)[:-1], str(list2)[1:])
```

which returns:

```
"['1', '2', '3'; '4', '5', '6']"
```

The `[:-1]` excludes the closing `]` of the first list and the `[1:]` the opening `[` of the second list.